# Creating a heatmap in Leaflet Js

Tags: javascript, json, ajax, leaflet, heatmap

I am trying to create a Leaflet map using this [solution](https://chat.openai.com/c/5fdf2948-e40b-42c7-bcad-fb21bd24c08f). I pasted the code to my javascript file called `heatmap.js` which is referenced in a `<script>` tag of my html file called `map.html`.

The code I pasted into my `heatmap.js` is as follows.

```
var map = L.map('myMap').setView([0.3556, 37.5833], 6.5);

L.tileLayer('https://tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
    attribution: '&copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
}).addTo(map);

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////
var geoJsonUrl = "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/sammigachuhi/geojson_files/main/selected_hospitals.json";

L.geoJson.ajax(geoJsonUrl, {
    //

    success: function (geoJSON) {
      // Create a heatmap layer and add the GeoJSON data to it
      var heatmapLayer = L.heatLayer(geoJSON.features.map(function (feature) {
        return [feature.geometry.coordinates[1], feature.geometry.coordinates[0]];
      }))
    }
  }).addTo(map);

heatmapLayer.setOptions({
    // Customize heatmap options here, such as radius, gradient, etc.
    radius: 40,
    blur: 10, 
    gradient: {
            '0': 'Navy', '0.25': 'Navy',
            '0.26': 'Green',
            '0.5': 'Green',
            '0.51': 'Yellow',
            '0.75': 'Yellow',
            '0.76': 'Red',
            '1': 'Red'
            }
});

heatmapLayer.addTo(map); // Add the heatmap layer to the map
```

The purpose is to create a heatmap and the Leaflet.heat plugin is already included in my html file as `<script src="my-directory\Leaflet.heat-gh-pages\dist\leaflet-heat.js"></script>`.

Running the Javascript code only generates the json features as marker points, which are actually hospital locations, however, my main interest is generating a heatmap from the json file.

[image]

Running the above code generates this error in the console:

[image]

I know variables in local scope cannot be available in global scope, but being clever by even inserting the `heatmapLayer.setOptions` and `heatmapLayer.addTo(map)` within the `L.geoJson.ajax` especially after the `success` key yields no results.

How can I create a heatmap in leafletjs using `L.heatLayer` and a json file in a server?

Comment: If you still need a solution: [codepen](https://codepen.io/svystunp/pen/xxyNpZa ). I don't like leaflet Ajax plugin, so solved via xhr request.

Comment: Hello, I managed to sort it out using the js here-- https://www.dropbox.com/s/49ichaa4ozfwry5/heatmap.js?dl=0 which was extracted from someone with a similar problem here -- https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/337294/heatmap-with-geojson-leaflet-and-leaflet-heat-plugin?utm_source=pocket_reader